# Sylius product API, image upload

Tags: image, api, upload, product, sylius

I have hard time trying to upload image through product API(http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/api/products.html). I managed find some samples in tests but it was not wery usefull(https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/tests/Controller/ProductApiTest.php);

Anyone knows working examples with guzzle or similar clients, that would be wery helpfull, cause i cant find any working example neither in documentation or web.

Comment: Same issue, if anyone has the answer...